# do not see Preview Assistant in my xcode 6, xcode 7 beta

Tags: ios, xcode

I do not see Preview Assistant in my Xcode 6, Xcode 7 beta. How do I open Preview Assistant?  The app is for both iPhone iPad and for all orientations.

Comment: Do you want to preview your app's user interface?

Comment: I want to see how it will look on iPad and iPhone 5,6 simultaneously

Comment: Make sure you have the storyboard open in primary editor, before opening the assistant editor. Then you should be able to see preview assistant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open a storyboard or xib file in Interface Builder.

Choose View > Assistant Editor > Show Assistant Editor.

The implementation file that corresponds to the storyboard or xib file opens in the assistant editor.

Open the Assistant pop-up menu.

The Assistant pop-up menu is the first item to the right of the back and forward arrows in the assistant editor jump bar.

In the pop-up menu, scroll to the Preview item and choose the storyboard or xib file.

A preview of the layout appears in the assistant editor. (For Mac apps, if a preview doesn’t appear, select a view in the icon or outline view.)

Choose preview options.

To preview your layout in a different localization, select a language from the pop-up menu in the lower-right corner of the preview.

To preview the layout of an iOS app for different devices on different versions of iOS, click the Add button in the lower-left corner of the preview and choose a device from the pop-up menu.

Comment: Thanks, thats help.
I also used bottom picture from this post http://ijoshsmith.com/2014/09/27/maximizing-the-preview-assistant-editor-in-xcode-6/
 to open preview

Comment: I get the Assistant to come up but not popup-menu or icon to choose the Preview , do I need a special version of OSx???? Tried it with xcode6/7

Comment: @Christophorus do you know how to preview in different versions?